# Special charater to Naming Entity Conversion in xml tag using VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net

Following Thing is my input

```
<tag>If milk prices increased from €355 to €420/t</tag>
```

I need to  convert like following

```
<tag>If milk prices increased from &euro;355 to &euro;420/t</tag>
```

I tried following code:

```
dim tmpstr as String = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(outStr)
```

But it convert xml tag < that also i need to perform inner xml only. how to convert that thing?

Comment: Do you expect `<tag>If milk prices increased from &euro;355 to &euro;420/t</tag>` to work with or without a DTD declaring the entity `euro`?

Answer (score 0):

create xml doc

```
 Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
 doc.LoadXml("yourstr")
 dim InnerText as string = doc.ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText
```

now you can do what you want to innertext

for all nodes you can use this

```
For Each node As XmlNode In doc.ChildNodes
       Dim innertext As String = node.InnerText
       innertext = innertext.Replace("*", " ")
       node.InnerText = innertext
Next
```